# AS3: Reading Filters currently applied to MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having a MovieClip on the stage with an "Adjust Color" filter applied to it through the properties panel not through action script, however, I need to read the filter values from AS3 to be able to use them on other classes.

I know how to apply the effect through AS3 but not to read it back if its applied from outside the code.

Thanks in advance :))

Answer (score 1):

There's a [`filters`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#filters) property, which is an array of the current filters.

```
trace(target.filters);
```

The 'adjust color' filter creates a [`ColorMatrixFilter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html) object. This class does not actually expose the properties `brightness`, `contrast`, `saturation` or `hue` - these are niceties that the UI provides, which actually translate to the more complex data found in the [`matrix`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html#matrix) array.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, also you will get the filter type being traced if you write:
          trace(target.filters[0]);
but still, how to get the data assigned inside this filter ??

Comment: Thanks for your answer :))
so you are saying it is impossible or extremely difficult to read those values from the code??

Comment: @Ahmed Unfortunately yes. I'm sure there's a formula that will translate the matrix values into those four channels, but that is outside of my skill level.

Comment: I will have to try to do it manually then.
Thanks a lot Marty for your help :)

Comment: @Ahmed I'm sure some googling will eventually yield some information. For example, this looks easy enough to reverse-engineer: http://chargedweb.com/labs/2010/04/30/fast_brightness_contrast_saturation/

Comment: I've googled around a lot but reversely reading this effect specifically seems so difficult and needs lots of digging.